# Prove that for even $n$ and $x<-1$, $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}>0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

> Prove that, for even $n$ and $x<-1$, $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}>0$

I have thought of making this factorisation:
$$x^n\left(\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(n-2k\right)!}\frac{1}{x^{2k}}\right)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(n-\left(2k+1\right)\right)!}\frac{1}{x^{2k+1}}\right)\right)$$
Since $x^n$ is positive, then if the parenthesis is positive, the sum must also be positive.
I have tried to find a lower bound and see how it behaves:
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(n\right)!}\frac{1}{x^{2k}}\right)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\frac{1}{x^{2k+1}}\right)<\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(n-2k\right)!}\frac{1}{x^{2k}}\right)+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(n-\left(2k+1\right)\right)!}\frac{1}{x^{2k+1}}\right)$$
But the left sums sum to a negative number, close to zero past $-3$, but really low close to $-1$, so it doesn't actually work.

Any hints please? Thank you very much!

*I have deleted the other post because of an error I have made and for the sake of a better explanation and a clearer presentation.*

Mr. [Eric Towers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/123905/eric-towers) suggested in the other post that:

> $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!} = \mathrm{e}^x  \text{,}$$
>   which is positive for all $x$, including $x<−1$. For $x<0$, this is an alternating series, where every even indexed term is positive. This means that the even indexed partial sums, which are the sums you ask about, are greater than $e^x>0$, so are positive.

I see that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}>e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}+\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-2}{2}}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\right]$$
but I don't see how it holds for finite $n$.

Comment: You might want to leave a comment to that effect with the other question. Someone spent time writing a suggestion for you there.

Comment: @copper.hat done, thank you.

Comment: Follow Eric's suggestion and consider cases ${|x| \over n} \le 1$ and $>1$ separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n} {\frac{{x^k }}{{k!}}}  = e^x  - \frac{{x^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n+1)!}}e^\xi   = e^x  + \frac{{\left| x \right|^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n+1)!}}e^\xi   > 0,
$$
where $x<\xi<0$ is a suitable number.

Comment: I cannot see where the minus sign in the remainder term comes from; am I missing anything?

Comment: @W-t-P Yes you are :) Write $$
e^x  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{2n} {\frac{{x^k }}{{k!}}}  + \frac{{x^{2n + 1} }}{{(2n + 1)!}}e^\xi  
$$ and re-arrange it.

Comment: Thank you, Gary!